# Adding live webcam texture to OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opencv, textures, shader, augmented-reality

I followed the examples of [the OpenGL Book](http://openglbook.com/blog/) and extended it to show a .3ds file. I also managed to use OpenCV to get an image from my webcam, apply the surf operator to it and find the homography for a given marker. The found transformation is then applied to the 3D model. However I'm unable to use the webcams picture as a textured background in my program. Following some examples for this creating the texture seems to work but I can't display it because it seems to break the shaders defined in the OpenGL book chapters. As soon as I try `glUseProgram` returns error 1282 while trying to use the predefined shader programs.

The shader code can be found at the given OpenGL Book link. My code for creating the texture is as follows:

```
void setze_hintergrund()
{
    if(gp_DataArray->zugriff_bild == false){
/*gp_DataArray is provided to both threads (opencv & opengl) to exchange data like the webcam picture*/

        return;
    } else {

        // alte Textur löschen
        glDeleteTextures(1, &backgroundid);

        // lade das Bild als Textur
        glGenTextures(1, &backgroundid);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundid);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
            gp_DataArray->kamerabild->width, gp_DataArray->kamerabild->height,
            0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gp_DataArray->kamerabild->imageData);
    }

    return;
}

void zeichne_hintergrund()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);

    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();   

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backgroundid);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
        glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(1, -1, -1); // Texturkoordinate rechts oben, Punkt rechts oben hinten setzen
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1); // Texturkoordinate links oben, Punkt links oben hinten setzen
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1); // Texturkoordinate links unten, Punkt links unten hinten setzen
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(1, 1, -1); // Texturkoordinate rechts unten, Punkt rechts unten hinten setzen
    glEnd ();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //glLoadMatrixf(ProjectionMatrix);
    //ProjectionMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ShaderIds[0], "ProjectionMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ProjectionMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, ProjectionMatrix.m);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    return;
}
```

Comment: The code you're using is deprecated. Please take a look at [this decent, up-to-date tutorial](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut)

Comment: Never use the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: @Bartek: The odd thing is, he *is* using an up-to-date tutorial. That tutorial doesn't include any removed functionality. So he must have cribbed that code from some other tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you should not use deprecated functions. Most of the deprecated code is seen in zeichne_hintergrund().
When you want to use the webcam image as a background for further rendering then you should use a FBO (framebuffer object). With the help of the FBO you are able to load the webcam image to a buffer and then use the same buffer for rendering. Then you can load this buffer to a texture and display it on the screen just as you tried it in your zeichne_hintergrund() function.

The vertex and fragment shader for rendering the texture that I once used look like this:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 430

layout(location=0) in vec4 currentPos;
layout(location=1) in vec2 texPos;
out vec2 ex_TexCoor;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = currentPos;
    ex_TexCoor = texPos;
}
```

currentPos is the position of the vertex and texPos is the associated uv-coordinate.

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430

in vec2 ex_TexCoor;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main(void){
    color = texture2D(texture, ex_TexCoor);
}
```

ex_TexCoor is the uv-coordinate from the vertex shader and texture is the webcam image with the rendered scene on it in this particular case.